# what can we do to make 1 flex item resizeable and one absolute length?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I want to make one element with a height and width of 40px and another element next to it which takes leftover space of parent element's width. so, after resize the second element will shrink and the first one will remain same.

My idea is to use flexbox properties for it, but if there isn't one I can use anything else to... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: left one has fixed width and you can vary it according to your requirement

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzw9wL22/) and below is a working code snippet

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
#column-2
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:red;
    border: 0.2em solid black;
    flex-shrink:0;
    flex-grow:1;
}
#column-1
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:200px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    border: 0.2em solid black;
    flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="column-1">
 content
</div>
<div id="column-2">
test content
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: beqa, can you please tell me why you unaccepted my answer. I had `-15` rep from this answer

Comment: I am sorry, it might be a mistake. can I do something to give your reputation points back?

Comment: No, it's okay. it was a glitch and it's fixed. I got them back. thank you for responding.